# How to set connection between chrome extension and browser using P2P/WebRTC

Tags: google-chrome-extension, webrtc, peerjs

**What I have to do:**

Using a Chrome Extension, send the response of chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab (dataUrl) to another browser, without processing the base64 data on server. On this another browser, I will show the image to the user. This process will repeat every 3 seconds, approximately.

**Possible solutions:**

- P2P/WebRTC: I'm using [peerjs](http://peerjs.com/) library and it works fine, except for a reason:
  WebRTC doesn't work in Safari.
- WebServer: create a local WebServer with my extension, host the dateUrl and share.
  Problem:
  WebServer can only be created with Chrome Apps.

Does anyone have an ideia about how to solve any of my problems, or suggest another solution?

Comment: Desktop sharing is normally done via chrome.desktopCapture.chooseDesktopMedia.  You need to explain more about your use case.  Are these your requirements: presenter needs to be on Chrome but the viewers can be on any browser?

Comment: Yes, the viewers can be on any browser.  I'm using chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab because it doesn't prompt the user being captured, chrome.desktopCapture.chooseDesktopMedia prompts the user to select which screen he wants to share.

Comment: I suppose you could send that screen capture image data over a websocket and broadcast it to any viewer that is listening.  You wouldn't even need webRTC for this use case.  Shouldn't be possible, though, without a prompt because that could be a potential security breach.

Comment: I've tried socket.io and It does exactly that. The problem is that the data goes through my server, and I don't want that. I will try another way, thanks!